# Change output format of printed number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the related script:

```
window.onload = function calcPreco() {
for(const cloud of Array.from(document.getElementsByName("cloud"))) {
    fetch("_config/buscar_valor.php?id="+cloud.getAttribute("cloudid")+"&periodicidade=monthly")
     .then(res => res.text())
     .then(preco => {
        preco -= cloud.getAttribute("desconto");
        const valor = cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor").innerText = preco;
     })
    }
}
```

In this case, what is the correct way to apply a `replace(".", ",")` to this function? More specifically in: `const valor = cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor").innerText = preco;`

It is hiding the zero of the value, for example: **$14.9**

The correct output should be: **$14,90**

Comment: To know the correct way to apply replace(".", ",") we need to know what the current output is and what it should become.

Comment: I put in the question, the current output is: 14.9, I need the output to be: 14,90

Comment: What's the current value of `preco`? `$14.9`, `14.9`, `14,9`, any other?

Comment: since when is money formatted like `$14,90`?

Comment: @lealceldeiro.. the current output is: 14.9, I need the output to be: 14,90

Comment: @goldie...It's an application in BRL, so this format.(R$*)

Comment: split string on . add extra 0's to array[1] if needed, stick back together, have fun.

Comment: yourNumber.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","), considering you always need to show 2 decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Number#toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like this:

```
//...
const valor = cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor").innerText = '$' + preco.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
//...
```

```js
const preco = 14.9;

console.log('$' + preco.toFixed(2).replace('.', ','));
```

Comment: You can remove the extraneous call to `toString` since `toFixed` returns a string.